# 550 error when trying to set up Gmail to send mail as Hotmail

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

I'm trying to configure my Gmail account so that I can use it to send mail as my Microsoft address (let's say it's `example@hotmail.com`), but I'm getting a weird error.

I've already gone into Gmail's *Settings* > *Accounts and Import* and added the Hotmail address under the "Send mail as" section, using server `smtp.live.com`, on port 587 with TLS. Gmail is now asking me to verify that I own the Hotmail address via an e-mailed code.

Unfortunately, every automatic verification mail that Gmail sends to `example@hotmail.com` results in this:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> example@hotmail.com
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
>   Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain hotmail.com by mx4.hotmail.com. [65.55.92.184].
>
> The error that the other server returned was:
>   550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
>
> ----- Message suppressed -----

The exact Hotmail server varies but the message is otherwise the same.

Some quick searching shows that a 550 error usually results when an e-mail address is entirely invalid, as would happen if the account didn't exist. However, I can log into Hotmail as `example@hotmail.com` and when I manually type up an e-mail in Gmail and send it to `example@hotmail.com`, it goes through just fine.

What can I do to finish setting up this mail alias?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the SMTP server is `smtp-mail.outlook.com` not hotmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know why Gmail wants to send a test message to anyone, the only thing I had to do to prove myself the owner of the account was to provide the correct password. If you followed http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app, and set up the smpt as `smtp-mail.outlook.com`, and can send mails using the "From" selector, I wouldn't worry about the failed "test".

Comment: `example@hotmail.com` isn't the actual address. I just didn't want to post the actual address in the question.

Comment: Separately from the previous comment, sending mail does not work. Gmail won't let me send mail until I prove (to Google, at least) that I own the Hotmail account by passing its test. While I was writing the first half of this comment though, I restarted the whole procedure using the alternate SMTP server you mentioned in the comment under the question, and setup was successful, so if you update the answer I'll accept.

Comment: @Pops I set up my account yesterday (before writing this answer) and Gmail didn't asked me for a test email. I wrote what you said was the problem, but I would recommend also verifying the POP/IMAP configurations too and make sure they are as the guide says.